# How to get IIS Mimemap in VBScript

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic, mime-types, permission-denied

I am trying to get the Mime Type of an uploaded files. For doing this, I have the following code:

```
Public Function GetMimeType(ByVal File)
    Dim oMimeMap
    Dim vntMimeType
    Dim avntMap()
    Dim DotPos
    Dim Extension

    Set oMimeMap = GetObject("IIS://LocalHost/MimeMap")
```

I, however, get the following error:

**Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Permission denied: 'GetObject'**

Can someone please  help me what is incorrect?